# Add default value in a range of date if not exist (SQL - BIGQUERY)

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I need to add missing default value of 0 from a range of date.

```
id date        item  store  sells
1  2015-08-01  1     1      2
2  2015-08-03  1     1      4
3  2015-08-04  1     1      1
4  2015-08-01  3     2      2
5  2015-08-02  3     2      2
6  2015-08-04  3     2      5
```

After apply the insert or complete the values

```
id date        item  store  sells
1  2015-08-01  1     1      2
7  2015-08-02  1     1      0
2  2015-08-03  1     1      4
3  2015-08-04  1     1      1
4  2015-08-01  3     2      2
5  2015-08-02  3     2      2
8  2015-08-03  3     2      0
6  2015-08-04  3     2      5
```

I want to do this in Bigquery of google cloud, i could use `INSERT` or `SELECT`.

Comment: is there a table with all the dates?

Comment: no, but i know the range of the day. For the example here could be  from 2015-08-01 to 2015-08-04

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH start_end AS (
  SELECT item, store, MIN(date) start_date, MAX(date) end_date
  FROM `project.dataset.table`
  GROUP BY item, store
),
dates AS (
  SELECT item, store, date
  FROM start_end, UNNEST(GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY(start_date, end_date)) AS date
)
SELECT d.date, d.item, d.store, IFNULL(t.sells, 0) sell
FROM dates d
LEFT JOIN `project.dataset.table` t
ON d.date = t.date
AND d.item = t.item 
AND d.store = t.store
ORDER BY item, d.date
```

You can test / play with it using dummy date from your question as below

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 1 id, DATE '2015-08-01' date, 1 item, 1 store, 2 sells UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, DATE '2015-08-03', 1, 1, 4 UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, DATE '2015-08-04', 1, 1, 1 UNION ALL
  SELECT 4, DATE '2015-08-01', 3, 2, 2 UNION ALL
  SELECT 5, DATE '2015-08-02', 3, 2, 2 UNION ALL
  SELECT 6, DATE '2015-08-04', 3, 2, 5 
),
start_end AS (
  SELECT item, store, MIN(date) start_date, MAX(date) end_date
  FROM `project.dataset.table`
  GROUP BY item, store
),
dates AS (
  SELECT item, store, date
  FROM start_end, UNNEST(GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY(start_date, end_date)) AS date
)
SELECT d.date, d.item, d.store, IFNULL(t.sells, 0) sell
FROM dates d
LEFT JOIN `project.dataset.table` t
ON d.date = t.date
AND d.item = t.item 
AND d.store = t.store
ORDER BY item, d.date
```

The output is as below

```sql
date        item    store   sell     
2015-08-01  1       1       2    
2015-08-02  1       1       0    
2015-08-03  1       1       4    
2015-08-04  1       1       1    
2015-08-01  3       2       2    
2015-08-02  3       2       2    
2015-08-03  3       2       0    
2015-08-04  3       2       5
```

> Update for follow up in comment:   what about the id? because in bigdata doesn't have autoincrement

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH start_end AS (
  SELECT item, store, MIN(DATE) start_date, MAX(DATE) end_date
  FROM `project.dataset.table`
  GROUP BY item, store
),
dates AS (
  SELECT item, store, DATE
  FROM start_end, UNNEST(GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY(start_date, end_date)) AS DATE
)
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY IFNULL(id, 999999999), d.item, d.date) id, d.date, d.item, d.store, IFNULL(t.sells, 0) sell
FROM dates d
LEFT JOIN `project.dataset.table` t
ON d.date = t.date
AND d.item = t.item 
AND d.store = t.store
ORDER BY d.item, d.date
```

You can test / play with it using below dummy data

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 1 id, DATE '2015-08-01' DATE, 1 item, 1 store, 2 sells UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, DATE '2015-08-03', 1, 1, 4 UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, DATE '2015-08-04', 1, 1, 1 UNION ALL
  SELECT 4, DATE '2015-08-01', 3, 2, 2 UNION ALL
  SELECT 5, DATE '2015-08-02', 3, 2, 2 UNION ALL
  SELECT 6, DATE '2015-08-04', 3, 2, 5 
),
start_end AS (
  SELECT item, store, MIN(DATE) start_date, MAX(DATE) end_date
  FROM `project.dataset.table`
  GROUP BY item, store
),
dates AS (
  SELECT item, store, DATE
  FROM start_end, UNNEST(GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY(start_date, end_date)) AS DATE
)
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY IFNULL(id, 999999999), d.item, d.date) id, d.date, d.item, d.store, IFNULL(t.sells, 0) sell
FROM dates d
LEFT JOIN `project.dataset.table` t
ON d.date = t.date
AND d.item = t.item 
AND d.store = t.store
ORDER BY d.item, d.date
```

The output is

```sql
id  date        item    store   sell     
1   2015-08-01  1       1       2    
7   2015-08-02  1       1       0    
2   2015-08-03  1       1       4    
3   2015-08-04  1       1       1    
4   2015-08-01  3       2       2    
5   2015-08-02  3       2       2    
8   2015-08-03  3       2       0    
6   2015-08-04  3       2       5
```

Note: above update is solely based on your limited example provided in your question and can potentially not cover all cases

Comment: what about the id? because in bigdata doesn't have autoincrement

Comment: in bigdata you rarely need auto-incremented id. If you have problem to use your data without id - just post new question and we will be happy to help you. but based on what I see in your original question  - id is totally not needed

Comment: WITH start_end AS (
  SELECT item, store, MIN(date) start_date, MAX(date) end_date
  FROM ``project.dataset.table``
  GROUP BY item, store
),
dates AS (
  SELECT item, store, date
  FROM start_end, UNNEST(GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY(start_date, end_date)) AS date
)
SELECT (select max(id) ``fromproject.dataset.table``)+1) id, d.date, d.item, d.store, IFNULL(t.sells, 0) sell
FROM dates d
LEFT JOIN ``project.dataset.table`` t
ON d.date = t.date
AND d.item = t.item 
AND d.store = t.store
ORDER BY item, d.date

Comment: see update in my answer  - covering id creation. If you have new question  - please post it as NEW Question/Post and we will be able to answer. Please DO NOT add it to your current question and DO NOT ask new question within a comment!